# Tilde expansion without eval

Tags: bash

I need to get user home folder. At the moment I'm using this

```
home=$(eval echo ~$user)
```

Content of `$user` is provided by the caller, so not trusted value. Is the use of the `eval` dangerous here? If yes (probably), how to solve it without it?

Comment: something like `$(cd ~;pwd)` maybe?

Comment: @n0rd - I think OP means that they need to get the home folder of a given username, the username specified from an untrusted source.

Comment: `eval` is dangerous on *unvalidated* input; you can make sure that `$user` contains only a valid user name with something like `[[ $user =~ [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_] ]] && home=$(eval echo ~$user)`. (I don't recall precisely what constitutes a valid user name, but it's something like a valid identifier.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On systems that have it, you can use [`getent(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getent):

```
$ getent passwd "$username" | cut -d: -f 6
/path/to/user/home
```

Make sure to check for empty results though.

Comment: Cool, I'll go with this, thanks. Works on my linux box. Remains to see if it also works in cygwin though.

Answer (score 2):

Tilde expansion occurs very early in the parsing process, and there are no ways to achieve what you want without several evaluations. Hence `eval` *is* a solution. The safest way to achieve what you want is:

```
eval "$(printf "home=~%q" "$user")"
```

Thanks to the `%q` modifier, the expansion `$user` will be fully quoted, so there's no danger here (don't modify the line though, you'll certainly introduce some security holes).

You shouldn't use this on its own: after this line, you must check that you get a valid directory, e.g.,

```
if [[ ! -d $home ]]; then
    echo >&2 "Couldn't find home dir for user $user"
    exit 1
fi
```

Also consider the case when `user` is empty: in that case, `home` will be the home directory of the user running the script. Whether you want this behavior or not is up to you.

There another point to consider: when `user` contains slashes: whether you want this feature or not is up to you.

Now, depending on what features you want to have, it's might be better to validate the expansion `$user` against some predefined pattern once for all, e.g.,

```
if [[ $user != [a-z]*([-a-z0-9_]) ]]; then
    echo >&2 'Provided user doesn't match valid pattern'
    exit 1
fi
```

And it turns out that with this validation, your solution is safe.

---

Examples:

A case where everything works well:

```
$ user=gniourf
$ eval "$(printf "home=~%q" "$user")"
$ declare -p home
declare -- home="/home/gniourf"
```

A case that would be dangerous with your code (with your code, `ls` would be executed, but not here):

```
$ user='; ls >&2'
$ eval "$(printf "home=~%q" "$user")"
$ declare -p home
declare -- home="~; ls >&2"
```